# For a Euclidean function, $f(a)>f(0)$ for all $a\in D$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand why for a Euclidean function, $f(a)>f(0)$ for all nonzero $a\in D$

Suppose $a$ is an element of an integral domain $D$ equipped with a Euclidean function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. By definition, $f$ satisfies the following two properties: 1. For all $a\in D, f(ab)\geq f(a)$ for all $b\neq 0$; and 2. If $a,b\in D, b\neq 0$, then there exist $c,d\in D$ such that $a=bc+d$ and $f(d)<f(b)$.

I don't know how $f(a)>f(0)$ follows from these conditions. How can I proceed?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, fixed.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the division "algorithm" formed by $a = a\cdot 1 + 0$.  Then by the last condition, $f(0) \lt f(a)$.  There are some gaps to be filled in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I have always seen the hypothesis *non-negative integers* in the definition of an euclidean function.

Then, take $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$ in your condition $(2)$, then $0=bc+d$, i.e. $d=-bc$, so if $c\neq 0$, $f(d)=f(b(-c))\geq f(b)$, but, on the other hand $f(d)<f(b)$. Hence $c=0$, so $d=0$, which gives $f(0)=f(d)<f(b)$ for any $b\in D$, $b\neq 0$.

Re hardmath: it is not enough to consider *one possible division*, you need to show that the reminder is **necessarily** zero.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\neq 0$ we have
$$a =ab+c$$
for some $b, c$ with $f(c) <f(a) $. Then
$$(1-b)a=c$$
If $c\neq 0$, then
$$f(a) >f(c) =f((1-b)a)\geq f(a) $$
which is a contradiction. Thus $c=0$, and it follows that $f(0)<f(a)$. Since $a$ was arbitrary we are done.